# How to move TODO Tree (Visual Studio Code) Extension from the Activity Bar to the Explorer Bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, todo

It is very distracting and unproductive to me, to go through the following everytime I create a TODO Tree note:

1. create note and save
2. leave Explorer bar
3. enter Activity bar
4. click on TODO Tree just to view notes.

On YouTube I've seen where someone had the TODO Tree extension visible from the Explorer bar.

Answer (score 5):

You can click and drag TODO Tree from the activity bar into the Explorer pane when it's open. I spent a long time trying to figure this out myself and it's very unintuitive that you can't set it with a configuration or setting, only by clicking and dragging where you want to move it.

Comment: It is even worse. I had to first drag the TODO tree to 'a panel of its own' (or something), that panel I could drag into the Explorer pane.

Comment: I'm just glad that it's possible

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that was the way to do it